# Join query with alias name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a query to search for three things, a keyword, a category and a region (it's for vacancies). Everything works except for the region since I get that column from my database with an aliased name.

My code now:

```
$functie = $_POST['functie'];
$branche = $_POST['branche'];
$regio = $_POST['regio'];

$search = "
SELECT cnt.title as content_title, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) as regio
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid
LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
";
// Collect all the where conditions in an array
$whr = array();

// check if $functie has some value in input filter
if (!empty($functie)) {
    $whr[] = "cnt.title LIKE '%" . $functie . "%'";
}

if (!empty($regio)) {
    $whr[] = "f.value LIKE '%" . $regio . "%'";
}

// check if $branche has some value in input filter
if (!empty($branche)) {
    $whr[] = "cat.title LIKE '%" . $branche . "%'";
}

$where_sql = '';
// Prepare where part of the SQL
if (!empty($whr)) {

    $where_sql = ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $whr);
}

// Append to the original sql
$search .= $where_sql;
$searchcon = $conn->query($search);
```

But above code is not working for the region.

However this is the endresult query and these are the results I get with it:

```
SELECT cnt.title as content_title, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) as regio
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid
LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE cnt.title LIKE '%vrachtwagen%'
```

[image]

`regio` is what I want to show results for.

But `WHERE regio LIKE '%" . $regio . "%'";` is not working, it says unknown column `regio` because it is an alias. How can I only show all results belonging to the region that was posted? For example above image, show only that row when `Drenthe` is the posted region.

Comment: which version of  mysql  db you are using ??

Comment: @scaisEdge mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: whic version of db not which ide  ..

Comment: @twan Please elaborate further the logic for determining `regio`; maybe there is a different way around.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use an aliased calculation expression in the `Select` clause inside the `Where` clause. Remember that `Select` is evaluated after `Where`, so expression evaluation happens afterwards.

You will have to specify the complete expression again in the `Where` clause.

```
// check if $regio has some value in input filter
if (!empty($regio)) {
    $whr[] = "MAX(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) LIKE '%" . $regio . "%'";
}
```

Comment: I get: `There was an error running the query [Invalid use of group function]`

Comment: @twan why do you use `Max()` function without `Group By` ?

Answer (score 0):

looking to your code seems you are trying to filter  ana ggregated result max(...) as regio

for filter an aggregated  result you should use  having

```
HAVING regio  like concat('%', $your_value, '%')
```

anyway  you are using php var inside sql this your code is at risk for sqlinjecttion  .. you should take a look at your db driver for prepared statement and binding param

You are also using not aggregated  column in select without group by .. this is deprecated  in sql, the result for the columns in unpredictable and in most recent version of mysql in not allowed.